# Fineuploader - onComplete will not fire

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

Using FineUploader ( http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/callbacks.html ) -- all my code works perfectly, with the exception of the onComplete callback. Simply doesn't fire - can't see what I might be doing wrong, have even used a copy/paste version from the demo. I have also tried a "jquery" style of setting this up, again with no console.log() output on complete.

```
            function createUploader() {
            var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
                element: document.getElementById('fine-uploader'),
                // Use the relevant server script url here
                action: '/admin/upload',
                debug: true,
                callbacks: {
                    onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON) {
                        console.log('response');
                        if (responseJSON.success) {
                            console.log('success');
                        //$('#thumbnail-fine-uploader').append('<img src="img/success.jpg" alt="' + fileName + '">');
                    }
                }
              }
            });
        }
        window.onload = createUploader;
```

EDIT: Firebug does not throw any errors for this; syntax is correct

Comment: note the missing single quote and indentation error

Comment: yeah, I'm checking if I have a typo from my fixing a typo - sorry, one moment

Comment: ok, apologies - thought I had a typo & messed it up fixing. Above code is what is in app right now

Comment: there is still a missing single quote at `/admin/upload`. Can you verify that this isn't also a problem in your source?

Comment: sorry again - 6am here, coffee not yet kicked in. Quoting is correct in my app (I removed additional query params that just cluttered the code for reading)

Comment: haven't you tried setting breakpoints and examining the code?

Comment: That's what the console.log() are...the callback isn't being fired

Comment: The documentation link you posted is for the latest release of *Fine Uploader* (v 3.7.0), I notice you're using File Uploader which is a quite outdated version of the same thing. I'd suggest upgrading. There are so many bugs and browser fixes that have been put into the latest release, and quite possibly whatever problem you're having has been fixed.

Comment: thanks - that's the sort of advice I was searching for. Inherited app, was up to speed on the library itself. Will update & try -- Gah! Didn't even notice FineUploader vs. FileUploader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Echoing @meltner, you are following documentation for a current version of Fine Uploader and applying this to a very old version of the library.  The API changed in several breaking ways starting with version 3.0.  One change included a move of all callbacks to a callbacks option.  Another included a change from FileUploader to FineUploader.  The version you are using is definitely pre-3.0.  Consider upgrading at http://fineuploader.com.